# Cannot change console colors

Tags: powershell, colors, console

I have tried to use these to customise my PowerShell console, but they all seem broken. The BackgroundColor goes black, but as soon as I type something like `dir` everything is in the default blue background again. I've been doing quite a few web searches and cannot find a way to just change this. Do you know a way to change the console so that I can make the `BackgroundColor` hold?

```
$Shell = $Host.UI.RawUI
$Shell.BackgroundColor = "Black"
$Shell.ForegroundColor = "White"
$Shell.CursorSize = 10
```

This page suggests adding these values to `$profile` to make them stick in the console session, but this does not work. https://4sysops.com/wiki/change-powershell-console-syntax-highlighting-colors-of-psreadline/

Is there some other PSReadLine function (possibly a PS v5.1 option) that does allow permanently fixing the console colors in a session?

```
* Set-PSReadLineOption options have changed
  - To specify colors, use the new `-Color` parameter and pass a Hashtable
```

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSReadLine/2.0.0-beta1/Content/Changes.txt

No example on how to change backgroundcolor though...

Answer (score 0):

There is the default native console colors and settings, which is separate from PSReadline configs

['PowerShell rest console colors'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20rest%20console%20colors%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=756e87c9340b4962b2d097c3c27f9d04&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20rest%20console%20colors%27&sc=2-32&qs=n&sk=&cvid=756e87c9340b4962b2d097c3c27f9d04)

```
$host.PrivateData
<#
# Results

...
ErrorForegroundColor                      : #FFFF0000
ErrorBackgroundColor                      : #00FFFFFF
WarningForegroundColor                    : #FFFF8C00
WarningBackgroundColor                    : #00FFFFFF
VerboseForegroundColor                    : #FF00FFFF
VerboseBackgroundColor                    : #00FFFFFF
DebugForegroundColor                      : #FF00FFFF
DebugBackgroundColor                      : #00FFFFFF
ConsolePaneBackgroundColor                : #FF012456
ConsolePaneTextBackgroundColor            : #FF012456
ConsolePaneForegroundColor                : #FFF5F5F5
ScriptPaneBackgroundColor                 : #FF1E1E1E
ScriptPaneForegroundColor                 : #FFD4D4D4
...
#>

[System.Enum]::GetValues('ConsoleColor')
<#
# Results

Black
DarkBlue
DarkGreen
DarkCyan
DarkRed
DarkMagenta
DarkYellow
Gray
DarkGray
Blue
Green
Cyan
Red
Magenta
Yellow
White
#>


[System.Enum]::GetValues('ConsoleColor') | 
ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $_ }
<#
# Results

DarkGreen
DarkCyan
DarkRed
DarkMagenta
DarkYellow
Gray
DarkGray
Blue
Green
Cyan
Red
Magenta
Yellow
White
#>

# Setting console color
$host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = "White"
```

> Reset console colors - [Console.ResetColor Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.resetcolor?view=netframework-4.8)

```
[Console]::ResetColor()

# Playing with colors
foreach($color1 in (0..15))
{
    foreach($color2 in (0..15))
    {Write-Host -ForegroundColor ([ConsoleColor]$color1) -BackgroundColor ([ConsoleColor]$color2) -Object "X" -NoNewline}

    Write-Host 
}
```

Someone once said:

> PowerShell 5.0 on Windows 10 ships with a
>   much-enhanced and colorful PowerShell console. PowerShell 5.0 on other
>   operating systems just has the dull standard console.
>
> That's because the console enhancements come from a module called
>   "PSReadLine". If you installed PowerShellGet (which is always part of
>   PowerShell 5.0 and can be downloaded from www.powershellgallery.com
>   for older PowerShell versions), you can download this module and turn
>   your console into a colorful beast as well:

```
# download and install the module
Install-Module PSReadLine -Scope CurrentUser

# load the module to turn on the colors
# this could be done automatically in your $profile script
Import-Module PSReadline
```

However, PSReadline is now in PowerShell distributions by default, no download needed. SO, there is a matter of precedence based on the config you choose. You can disable PSReadline, to validate if it is truly PSReadline as your root case or the default of PowerShell.

> [Set-PSReadLineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7)
>
> Set-PSReadLineOption    [-EditMode ]    [-ContinuationPrompt
>   ]    [-HistoryNoDuplicates]    [-AddToHistoryHandler ]
>   [-HistorySearchCursorMovesToEnd]    [-MaximumHistoryCount ]
>   [-MaximumKillRingCount ]    [-ShowToolTips]
>   [-ExtraPromptLineCount ]    [-DingTone ]
>   [-DingDuration ]    [-BellStyle ]
>   [-CompletionQueryItems ]    [-WordDelimiters ]
>   [-HistorySearchCaseSensitive]    [-HistorySaveStyle
>   ]    [-HistorySavePath ]
>   [-AnsiEscapeTimeout ]    [-PromptText ]
>   [-ViModeIndicator ]    [-ViModeChangeHandler
>   ]    [-Colors ]    []